# Org mode - autocomplete tags

Tags: org-mode, completion, auto-complete-mode, org-tags

When I try to enter tags, autocomplete is tedious. I do `C-c C-q` enter *first* few characters, hit `TAB` then select. And repeat if I want to add more than one tags.

I can do the same by entering `:` in the heading, enter the *first* few characters of the tag followed by `ESC TAB`.

I find both the option tedious. What I would love to have, instead, is after the heading, I enter `:` and ANY characters in a previously entered tag. Possible completions are shown right there. I select the one I want and enter a : and repeat if I want to add more tags.

Is there a way to achieve this? If it can not be done in the heading itself, I am OK with entering `C-c C-q` and doing the same thing.

Important thing is enter any characters, ignore case while matching, and choices are shown right there.

Comment: When it comes to Emacs, just about anything is possible.  The question is how much time would be involved to create a new feature, and what complications (if any) would ensue based thereon.  You may wish to consider experimenting with adding and removing a custom function to the `post-self-insert-hook` when it's time to insert a tag and auto-completion is desired; and/or, you may wish to utilize an `idle-timer` that would launch that custom function after a certain period of time of no activity (which can also be removed from the `timer-idle-list` when your are finished.